# SharePoint 2010 use month to return quarter

Tags: sharepoint, formulas

I have 2 columns labeled "Month" and "Quarter". Month is a choice column with options January->February. I am trying to construct a formula for the "Quarter" column so if one selects months Jan-Mar, "Quarter" is automatically "Quarter 1" and so on through "Quarter 4". I've messed around with IF(OR( functions but can't seem to get the formula right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculated column formula for Quarter field could be something like:

```
=IF(OR(Month="January", Month="February", Month="March"), "Quarter 1",
IF(OR(Month="April", Month="May", Month="June"), "Quarter 2",
IF(OR(Month="July", Month="August", Month="September"), "Quarter 3", 
IF(OR(Month="October", Month="November", Month="December"), "Quarter 4",
""))))
```

This makes sure that you have a valid month or the formula leaves the Quarter field blank.

Comment: Thanks!! I had most of the formula right. I forgot the ,"")))) part.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier, shorter way to do this, but I'm not sure exactly how well it will work if your field is based off a text value for the month. I use an actual date, and then I can manipulate the portions of that date anyway I want/need. For example, given a date of 6/22/2014, I can have it display the name of the month. Specifically, in your case, you could use the following formula:
=CHOOSE(MONTH([Month]),1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
It will choose a value from the list based on the number of the month. For example, for June, the 6th month, it would choose the 6th value in the list, 2.